# Flow calling Apex, can't pass Collection Variable

Tags: apex, visual-flows

I have an invokable apex method that I need to call from a Flow. Invokable methods are strict in the data type of their parameters -- I can't simply pass a string, instead, I have to pass a `list<String>`. OK, no biggie. Here's the method:

```
    public class ARpromptFirstName
{
    @InvocableMethod(label='Send AutoResponse FirstName' description='Needs ConversationIdList')
    public static void sendAutoResponseFirstName(List<String> ConversationIds)
    {
        for (String Id : ConversationIds)
        {
            String msgBody = 'Please enter your first name.';
            SaveSendSMS.sendSMSfromLightning(Id, msgBody);
        }
    }
}
```

The method works fine when I call it from Anonymous Apex. My problem is calling it from the Flow. The method shows up in the Flow palette, and I can drag it into the Flow, but it won't allow me to assign a collection variable to the ConversationIds parameter. It gives me the choice of all my other (singleton) variables, but not the collection variable named ConversationIds to which I have added the individual `{!ConversationId}` I need to pass. I think it's odd that it allows primitive data types to be passed to a parameter that is a `list<string>`. (And, no, the method won't work if I just pass a single string value instead of the list.) That suggests a breakdown in communications between the APEX method and the Flow Designer.

[image]

YES, the flow variable is set to Output (I've tried Input/Output as well). 
[image]

Checking the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_apex_invocable.htm), it says:

> Pass information from the flow to the invoked Apex method. The method
>   determines the available input parameters and their data types.

As you can see in the method code above, my method clearly indicates `list<string>`.  The flows editor doesn't allow you to be that clear when you create variables. I've created a "Collection Variable" of type "Text". I think that's about as close as one can get to a list of strings.

---

A day later...
I suspected that the flow's Collection variable of type Text isn't exactly a `list<String>`, so I've tried changing the method to accept a `list<Conversation__c>` parameter instead, creating an SObject Collection variable in the Flow. But guess what... that doesn't work either. Only the singular variables/sObject variables appear in the pulldown menu of items that can be assigned as the parameter when calling the APEX method. Frustrating... Flow can't send a list, APEX can only accept a list.

I've combed the docs for Invokable Apex and for the Flow Designer -- can't find anything I've overlooked. I'm hoping one of you can spot something... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here. Turns out, you can pass a singleton parameter into a `list<sObject>` Invokable Method. It appears to be like a trigger, where you write it for bulk, but it executes OK on an individual. I should have thought to test for that sooner.

Comment: yes, the analogy is like in PB to @invocable Apex. The invocable gets a collection but the PB action group defines the singleton; PB actions are "bulkified" before executing. There's a somewhat related [post on this here](http://cropredysfdc.com/2018/02/20/process-builder-bulkification-record-create/)

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same exact scenario. Another solution that worked for me was changing the @InvocableMethod parameter to: `List<List<String>>` and then reference the variable accordingly in the rest of the code. Once I did that and went back to my visual workflow APEX call element, I could choose or create a collection in the input parameters.

Comment: Your solution works.

Comment: OMG Salesforce ... okay.  A million thanks for coming up with this hack ... managed to do a `List<List<Custom_Object__c>>` this way, too.